Why is TALPA not used for take off? Why is it used for landing?
TALPA - Takeoff and Landing Performance Assessment has been introduced. What is it exactly and why is it not used for take-off, when it is stated in the name TALPA?

If you don't know what it is, then how can you be certain what it is or isn't used for?

I think TALPA is now replaced by ICAO defined Global Reporting Format (GRF). For landing performance assessment the RWYCC (0-6, average of the last two thirds of the runway) is sufficient. For takeoff performance assessment you need also the thickness and type of the thickest contaminant on the runway.
